# define type for Messages which Queue will accept in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, queue

Tech stack in use is **Typescript, Express, Nodejs, Mongoose & Mongodb**.

**Bull** library of Nodejs is being used to manage **Queues**.

*Can we restrict the type of messages which the queue will accept ?*

```
const data1 = {name: "Alpha", Age: 30};
const data1 = {name: "Beta", Age: 40};
const data3 = {color: "Red", taste: "sweet"}; // queue should give error on some other message structire being passed

queue.add(data1);
queue.add(data2);
queue.add(data3); // error should come here
queue.add
```

This is easy done in languages like Java with the help of Generics.

Any way out to achieve same in typescript ??

Comment: Typescript also has generics. You can extend the `Queue` class to make your own queue that overrides `add`, add the necessary typings to it and that's all there is to it. Not entirely sure if you'll even need generics for this since the examples you've given adhere to a strict interface - `{ name: string, Age: number }`

Comment: Actually I looked at the typings for `Bull`, and you can see [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/bull/index.d.ts#L462) that the typing takes in a `T` which is set to `any` by default. All you have to do in that case, is just mention the exact type while instantiating the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to mention the specific type you want during instantiating the queue-

```
interface QueueData {
  name: string;
  Age: number;
}

const myQueue = new Queue<QueueData>('name', options);
```

Comment: This solution is not giving compile time error on adding some thing other than ```QueueData```. I'll update soon, about RUN time behaviour

Comment: Can you also suggest me.. how to use this generic at Consumer end. So that instead of a  regular job object, I receive ```QueueData```